# Find the Longest Word in a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Return the length of the longest word in the provided sentence.

Your response should be a number. I am getting an error - unexpeted token).

```
 function findLongestWord(str) {

  var array = str.split(' ');
  var longest=0;
  for(var i =0;i<array.length,i++){

    if(array[i].length>longest)
      longest=array[i].length;

  }

  return longest;

}

findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

Comment: `(var i =0;i<array.length ; i++)` There should be a semi colon, instead of comma between for loop statements

Comment: There's a comma instead of a semicolon in the for statement.

    for(var i =0;i<array.length;i++){

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting an error - unexpeted token).

Yes, and the JavaScript parser in your browser (or whatever) is *also* helpfully telling you exactly where that error is.

```
for(var i =0;i<array.length,i++){
// Should be ; ------------^
```